# JavaFX project doesn't find my JDK FX version

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, azul-zulu

I'm fairly new at using IntelliJ IDEA and also Java language overall. I've downloaded newest (17.0.1+12) version of JDK FX from Azul and yesterday had some problems with it. My freshly created JavaFX HelloApplication project couldn't find JavaFX dependencies. It seems that the problem was caused by wrong versions in pom.xml file.

**When created, versions were:**

```
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
<version>17.0.0.1</version>
```

```
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
<version>17.0.0.1</version>
```

```
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.7</version>
```

**Then i manually changed them to:**

```
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
<version>17-ea+11</version>
```

```
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
<version>17-ea+11</version>
```

```
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.6</version>
```

This solution worked. When I created same new project again today, versions were set to those that didn't work previously, but actually work today somehow. What could have happened here? I'm really curious of what could have been done yesterday when the problem ocurred, because even though changing some versions manually does not seem like a hard work to do, but it is really strange that sometimes same things work and sometimes not (in the equivalent situations).

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like the problem was with the versions, but with sometime else you've changed along the way to solve the problem.

Maybe IntelliJ restart or Maven reimport changed this.

> My freshly created JavaFX HelloApplication project couldn't find JavaFX dependencies

It means that the problem is with the classpath IntelliJ uses when you click the `Run` button.